# How to replace all images in an html file with their base64-codes? (Powershell)

Tags: html, image, powershell, replace, base64

I use a software called [Belarc Avisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html), that provides an html output of all the hardware-software details including licenses/keys/serials of installed software in an html format. I usually create this report from this software either on a new PC or before formatting a PC. However the chrome exported file uses a separate folder for images, and I need a standalone html file with all the details and images (inclding css styles of the html report).

I presently had to replace the images in notepad++ with their base64 code that was generated from an online website. I'm looking for an alternative way to do this in either batch script or Powershell. I found two stackoverflow questions {[q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403217/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-file-using-powershell)}, {[q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649172/dynamically-insert-images-in-html-file)}, and a {[blog-post](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2010-11-07-base64-encoding-images-with-powershell.html)}, and have the following code:

```
    $original_file = 'path\filename.html'
    $destination_file =  'path\filename.new.html'
    (Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-IMG-SELECTOR-Object {
        $path = $_ SOURCE-TAG-SELECTOR `
        -replace $path, [convert]::ToBase64String((get-content $path -encoding byte))
    } | Set-Content $destination_file
```

In the `Foreach-Object`, maybe the object could be selected by the html img tag? If yes, then the base64 conversion would be quite easy!

for converting to base64, the string is: 
    `[convert]::ToBase64String((get-content $path -encoding byte))`

where `$path` is the path to the image. Could be just copied from the `<img src="">` tag.

I just read that Windows 10 has Powershell 5.0, so I thought I could create a batch file for creating this.

So if the `img` tags & the `src` attribute can be selected, they only have to be replaced by their base64 tags.

## Modified version of the **Answer**

The answer provided by Alexendar is invalid because during the loop, the attribute-Value is being set to the #Document, while it should be set to the current node. After searching online and reading the Powershell console, I found that this could be solved by Selecting the current node via XPath. Here's the modified answer:

```
Import-Module -Name "C:\HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.6\Net40\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" # Change to your actual path

function Convert_to_Base64 ($sImgFile)
{
#$sImgFile = "C:\image.jpg" # Change to your actual path
$oImgFormat = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Gif # Change to your format

$oImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($sImgFile)
$oMemoryStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.MemoryStream
$oImage.Save($oMemoryStream, $oImgFormat)
$cImgBytes = [Byte[]]($oMemoryStream.ToArray())
$sBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cImgBytes)

$sBase64
}


$sInFile = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\BelarcAdvisor win10\Belarc Advisor Computer Profile.html" # Change to your actual path
$sOutFile = "D:\Win10-Belarc.html" # Change to your actual path
$sPathBase = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\BelarcAdvisor win10\"

$sXpath = "//img"
$sAttributeName = "src"

$oHtmlDocument = New-Object -TypeName HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$oHtmlDocument.Load($sInFile)
$oHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($sXpath) | ForEach-Object {
    # If you need to download the image, here's how you can extract the image
    # URI (note that it may be realtive, not absolute):

    $sVarXPath = $_ #To get the Current Node and then later get Attributes + XPathXPath from this node variable.

    #$sVarXPath.XPath

    $sSrcPath = $sVarXPath.get_Attributes() `
        | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $sAttributeName } `
        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value"
    # Assembling absolute URI:
    $sUri = Join-Path -Path $sPathBase -ChildPath $sSrcPath.substring(2) #substring for "./" in the src string of the img in subfolder.
    #$sUri
    # Now you can d/l the image: Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $sUri
    #[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($sUri)

    # Put your Base64 conversion code here.
    $sBase64 = Convert_to_Base64($sUri)

    $sSrcValue = "data:image/png;base64," + $sBase64
    $oHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($sVarXPath.XPath).SetAttributeValue($sAttributeName, $sSrcValue)
    #$oHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($sVarXPath.XPath).GetAttributeValue($sAttributeName, "")
}

#$oHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($sXpath) | foreach-object { write-output $_ }

$oHtmlDocument.Save($sOutFile)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy. You could use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML:

```
Import-Module -Name "C:\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" # Change to your actual path

$sInFile = "E:\Temp\test.html" # Change to your actual path
$sOutFile = "E:\temp\test1.html" # Change to your actual path
$sUriBase = "http://example.com/" # Change to your actual URI base

$sXpath = "//img"
$sAttributeName = "src"

$oHtmlDocument = New-Object -TypeName HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$oHtmlDocument.Load($sInFile)
$oHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($sXpath) | ForEach-Object {
    # If you need to download the image, here's how you can extract the image
    # URI (note that it may be realtive, not absolute):
    $sSrcPath = $_.get_Attributes() `
        | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $sAttributeName } `
        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value"
    # Assembling absolute URI:
    $sUri = $sUriBase + $sSrcPath
    # Now you can d/l the image: Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $sUri


    # Put your Base64 conversion code here.
    $sBase64 = ...

    $sSrcValue = "data:image/png;base64," + $sBase64
    $_.SetAttributeValue($sAttributeName, $sSrcValue)
}

$oHtmlDocument.Save($sOutFile)
```

[Converting image file to Base64 string](http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx):

```
$sImgFile = "C:\image.jpg" # Change to your actual path
$oImgFormat = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg # Change to your format

$oImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($sImgFile)
$oMemoryStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.MemoryStream
$oImage.Save($oMemoryStream, $oImgFormat)
$cImgBytes = [Byte[]]($oMemoryStream.ToArray())
$sBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cImgBytes)
```

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the HTMLAgilityPack v.1.4.6... There are about 9 folders in the zip file. Which dll file should I use for my system? I'm on Windows 10 Home Edition 64bit. Folders included in the zip file are: `Net20 / Net40 / Net40-client / Net45 / sl3-wp / sl4 / sl4-windowsphone71 / sl5 /winrt45`

Comment: Depending on which versions of .NET you have on your PC. If you have .NET 4.5 installed, use the dell from `Net45` folder.

Comment: Also, what should the uri base be for `<img src="./Belarc Advisor Computer Profile_files/sp_ok.gif">` ... The image folder is in the same folder that the html file is in, and src has a `./` for the folder path.

Comment: If you have images already downloaded, use `[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile()` method to load them. Relative path should be enough.

Comment: Should I use `file:///C:/Temp/` as the `$sUriBase`? Or `C:\Temp\ `

Comment: If you want to use absolute paths, you can write something like `$sPathBase = "C:\Temp\"` and then `Join-Path -Path $sPathBase -ChildPath $sSrcPath`. It will convert slashes to backslashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86545/discussion-between-mk117-and-alexander-obersht).

Comment: Hi! the script ran without errors, although the output file's img src tags were not changed to base64... the complete html file output was unchaged.. I ran the script twice, yet no change in the html file...
*html file output was unchanged

Comment: Here's the edited version from your script that I'm trying to run [Script@pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tvYVNSh3)

Comment: Well, I tried adding code to the `ForEach-Object` loop (after `SetAttributeValue` line): `$oHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.GetAttributeValue($sAttributeName, "")` and the base64 code is present in each run of the img tag loop, although when I added the following code after the loop and before the save(), then the base64 is not present: `$oHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($sXpath) | foreach-object { write-output $_ }`, seems like the values are only present inside the `foreach` loop and the loop isn't transferring the base64 values to the respective image tags at all!

Comment: Please do correct your answer... The SetAttributeValue was setting the attribute for root #document, and not the active node. I have edited my question with the modified version of your answer...

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I meant to test my code but forgot. ) Corrected it and now it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks again! I didn't know I could just use `$_` for the active node. I was using a variable for that!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer here, but I was able to perform the conversion from a single image file to an output text file with data URI encoding in just one line:

`"data:image/png;base64," + [convert]::tobase64string([io.file]::readallbytes(($pwd).path + "\\image.png")) | set-content -encoding ascii "image.txt"`

(Note that the output file encoding seems to make a difference.)

Mainly posting this because this is what came up in my web search, and it also simplifies the conversion in Alexander's answer.